# WPF trouble applying a style to a textbox

Tags: wpf, textbox, styles

### I am a bit new to WPF and am in need of some assistance..   I am trying to setup a mouse over trigger event to change the 'style' of a textbox.. ie - when the user moves the mouse over the textbox, I want the border and background to change.  So, after doing some digging around and reading here and there on this, I ended up with this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="WMCTextBoxStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WMCTextBoxStyle}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation"  Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Border Name="Border1"
                            CornerRadius="3"
                            Padding="2"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Height="Auto" 
                            Width="auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFA4B3C5" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFA4B3C5" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>

                        <Border Name="Border2"
                            CornerRadius="0"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            BorderBrush="Black">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.225,-0.616" RadiusY="0.863" RadiusX="0.757">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#EEFFFFFF"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.696"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{DynamicResource WMCTextBoxStyle}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

---

### When I try to compile, I get the following two errors:

### Error   XDG0062 '{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.Controls.Control.Template' property on a Setter." in Line:12

### Error   XDG0062 Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies. in Line 19

I know that I am missing something basic on this, but not sure exactly how to get around it. When remove the  ---  out of the code, and then create a textbox and manually set the style, it works..  so I know that I am doing something wrong with the triggers...  and I am sure it is something basic and 'newbie' ish...

any help would be appreciated..  :)

### Here is the latest version

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="WMCTextBoxStyle"
       TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Border x:Name="border"
                           Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                             BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                             BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                             SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                    Focusable="false"
                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />

                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                   TargetName="border"
                                    Value="0.56" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                   Value="True">

                            <Setter TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Border Name="OuterBorder"
                                CornerRadius="3"
                                Padding="2"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                Height="Auto" 
                                Width="auto" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFA4B3C5" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFA4B3C5" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <Border Name="InnerBorder"
                                          CornerRadius="0"
                                            BorderThickness="1"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                             BorderBrush="Black">
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.225,-0.616" RadiusY="0.863" RadiusX="0.757">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#EEFFFFFF"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.696"/>
                                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Border>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
```

### Ok, for anyone that is interested in this, I decided to stick with one border and then changed a few things... here is what seems to be working.

<Window.Resources>

```
        <Style x:Key="WMCTextBoxStyle"
       TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                        <Border x:Name="border"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                        Focusable="false"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                   TargetName="border" Value="0.56" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"  Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.225,-0.616" RadiusY="0.863" RadiusX="0.757">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#EEFFFFFF"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.696"/>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFA4B3C5" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFA4B3C5" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>

                        </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        
    </Window.Resources>
```

--
Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

To understand how styles work, I recommend the following read (better don't skip it): [How to create a style for a control (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-apply-style?view=netdesktop-6.0) (and [Styles and templates in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/styles-templates-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)).

> "Error XDG0062 '{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.Controls.Control.Template' property on a Setter." in Line:12"

You can't base a `Style` n itself (doesn't make sense either - I'm sure this also creates a designer error, showing squiggles to indicate the exact erroneous piece of code).

```xml
<!-- Illegal 'BasedOn' reference to itself as base style -->
<Style x:Key="WMCTextBoxStyle" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource WMCTextBoxStyle}">
```

> "Error XDG0062 Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies. in Line 19"

You can't set the `Style` property from inside a `Style` that is the current value of the Style property. Apart from that it does not make sense to set the Style prooperty to itself.

```xml
<!-- Illegal modification of the Style property. Aside from that
     'WMCTextBoxStyle' is already the Style, otherwise the triggers are not in effect -->
<Setter Property="Style" Value="{DynamicResource WMCTextBoxStyle}"/>
```

When you define an explicit `Style` (a named `Style`), you must assign it explictly:

```xml
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource WMCTextBoxStyle}" />
```

The simplest `Style` to change the `BorderThickness`, `Background` and `BorderBrush` on mouse over is:

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="WMCTextBoxStyle"
           TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
            <Border x:Name="border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
              <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                            Focusable="false"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                       Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Opacity"
                        TargetName="border"
                        Value="0.56" />
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                       Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="OrangeRed" />
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="PaleGreen" />
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>

  <!-- Apply the Style -->
  <TextBox Style="{StaticResource WMCTextBoxStyle}" />
</Window>
```

If you are not interested in modifying the `BorderBrush` you can even skip the complete template and move the triggers to the `Style.Triggers` property.

Comment: "Thanks for the links... I read them and see what you were getting at.. however, I still have an issue ...  in the trigger section.   Basically, I took my original code and using your example, 'moved' my inner border, outer border and the code to set the background to the trigger event and when I try to apply the style to the textbox, I get a message stating "ArgumentException: Must have non-null value for 'Setter.Property'"

Comment: Would you mind to update your question to add your current version, please? It would help me to understand what is going on.

Comment: I know this sounds like a dumb question, but trying to figure out how to add code to this..

Comment: Please don't edit my answer. Edit your question. Please review your code and think about what you are currently doing there: you try to set a border "OuterBorder" to a border. This doesn't make sense and is not how it works. You must target the existing border and then set its properties - like I did in my answer. Beside from that your setter must also provide the Property. TargetName and Value is not enough. You always have to set at least Property and Value. TargetName is the only optional Setter property (in case you want to target a named element).

Comment: Create a setter inside the trigger for every property you want to change. My example only sets Background, BorderThickness and BorderBrush. But you can set every property of Border (or the targeted element in general). Just follow my example. Extend it by adding more Setter elements if required.

Comment: ok.. what I was trying to do is to change the existing border and then add a second 'inner' border and change the background of the button only when the mouse was over it.

Comment: Then add this second border to the layout and toggle the Visibility on mouse over.

Comment: Ok, I think that I have it figured out now... and am just using one border.

Comment: another question regarding this:  is there a way that this style can be applied to other types of controls.. example: buttons, combo boxes, etc..  or would i have to have a separate style for each?

Comment: The Style can be applied to any control that matches the Style.TargetType.

Comment: ok, I played with it a bit and now have it working on a button by copying what I had into a new <style> section and then change the names and types appropriately.